# How can I detect homepage.tpl in WHMCS in Smarty?

Tags: smarty, whmcs

I currently edit one template of WHMCS, it's written by Smarty.

Can I use something simple like

```
{if $is_homepage}
    show something
{/if}
```

Which **homepage** is loaded from homepage.tpl, mean index page. Because I want to load some code, just in homepage only.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite hacky but you might try something like this:

```
{if ($smarty.server.SCRIPT_NAME eq "/index.php")}

{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Could I ask you to explain something or give me some documentary about this, I want to learn, not just copy and paste. Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: Sure:
If you're taking a look at the structure of WHMCS (haven't heard of it before - I just took a look at the demo http://demo.whmcs.com/index.php) each menu item has its own php script (index.php -> Home, announcements.php -> Announcements, and so on).

So to detemine if the current state is "home" you just have to check the current script name inside the reserved {$smarty} variable. Tahe a look at: 

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl

Comment: Cleaner way: separate template and logic and set a marker inside index.php and just check inside homepage.tpl, if the marker is set.

Comment: Dude the function is not working for me. By the way this code for which version of smarty? It prints in all pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead if you desire optimized code.

```
{if $filename eq "index"} 
your code here 
{/if}
```

you don't have to include the filename extension like **.tpl** (just in case you were wondering)